# Deactivating desktop background when a pop up is shown to user

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui

I have a win32 application that runs full screen when started. The application has some button which invoke pop up dialogs.

Is there a way to make the entire desktop (except the pop up) go transparent black unless the pop up is dismissed by the user? what I am talking of is similar to windows 7 UAC pop ups and the background it causes.

Is it possible to do similar stuff for a full screened window app?

Comment: What about showing a fullscreen always-on-top window? Anyway I hope it's a requirement from the client, because as a user I won't like an application that does this. :-)

Comment: Can you elaborate it a little? you mean I create a window and keep it hidden and only when the dialog pops up I show it? What kind of window would that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible do this…sort of. Perhaps I should say, you can *simulate* this effect. It won't actually be like the UAC dialog, as the user will still be able to interact with other running applications. There is no such concept as "system modal" available to applications. That's by design, of course. But you can certainly show a "light box" that dims out the rest of the desktop and forces focus on your app's dialog box.

The way I would do it is to create a giant [layered window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx) that sits on top of all other windows and covers the entire screen, fill it with black, and set the opacity as desired. Then, before you show a modal dialog (either by calling the MessageBox function or using the DialogBox function to show one of your own custom dialogs), display your light box window. Finally, after the user dismisses the modal dialog, you will destroy the light box window.

Here's some sample code. Error checking is omitted for brevity. So is other good style, like wrapping this mess up in one or more classes.

```
INT_PTR ShowLightBoxedDialog(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                             LPCTSTR pDlgTemplate,
                             HWND hwndParent,
                             DLGPROC pDlgProc,
                             BYTE opacityLevel)
{
   const TCHAR szLightBoxClass[] = TEXT("LightBoxWndClass");

   // Register the light box window class.
   static bool lightBoxRegistered = false;
   if (!lightBoxRegistered)
   {
      WNDCLASSEX wcex;
      wcex.cbSize          = sizeof(wcex);
      wcex.style           = CS_NOCLOSE | CS_SAVEBITS;
      wcex.lpfnWndProc     = LightBoxWndProc;
      wcex.cbClsExtra      = 0;
      wcex.cbWndExtra      = 0;
      wcex.hInstance       = hInstance;
      wcex.hIcon           = NULL;
      wcex.hIconSm         = NULL;
      wcex.hCursor         = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
      wcex.hbrBackground   = NULL;
      wcex.lpszMenuName    = NULL;
      wcex.lpszClassName   = szLightBoxClass;
      RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
      lightBoxRegistered = true;
   }

   // Create and display the light box window.
   HWND hwndLightBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_LAYERED,
                                      szLightBoxClass,
                                      NULL,
                                      WS_POPUPWINDOW,
                                      0, 0, 0, 0,
                                      hwndParent,
                                      NULL,
                                      hInstance,
                                      NULL);
   SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwndLightBox, 0, opacityLevel, LWA_ALPHA);
   SetWindowPos(hwndLightBox,
                HWND_TOP,
                GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN),
                GetSystemMetrics(SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN),
                GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN),
                GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN),
                SWP_SHOWWINDOW);

   // Display the modal dialog box (as you normally would).
   // NOTE: The dialog box won't appear centered on the screen.
   // For that, you will need to write centering code in response
   // to the WM_INITDIALOG message in the dialog procedure.
   INT_PTR result = DialogBox(hInstance, pDlgTemplate, hwndLightBox, pDlgProc);
   // 
   // For demonstration purposes, I used the following code:
   // INT_PTR result = MessageBox(hwndLightBox,
   //                             TEXT("OH NOEZ!\n\nYour system is kaput! Abandon þe all hope."),
   //                             NULL,
   //                             MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE | MB_ICONERROR);

   // Destroy the light box window.
   DestroyWindow(hwndLightBox);

   // Return the result of the modal dialog box.
   return result;
}
```

You'll notice that basically what I've done is created a wrapper around the [DialogBox function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452.aspx), which you use whenever you want a dialog box with a "light box" effect. It takes all of the same parameters (the first 4), and then there's an additional one tacked on the end that allows you to specify the opacity level used for the "light box" effect. Something in the range of 150–200 is probably good. Naturally, you could pick something and hard-code it, but I suffer from severe allergies to hard-coded values. Anyway, it's super easy to call this function from anywhere:

```
ShowLightBoxedDialog(hInstance,                   /* your application instance */
                     MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_SAMPLE), /* your dialog template      */
                     hWnd,                        /* parent window for dialog  */
                     SampleWndProc,               /* ptr to dialog procedure   */
                     175);                        /* light box opacity level   */
```

[image]

Because the code takes advantage of how modal dialogs already work in Windows, the user won't be able to interact with any other pieces of your application until they dismiss the dialog box. And because the "light box" window is positioned on top of everything else, it eats all mouse clicks and prevents setting focus to any other application. But it is trivial to work around using something like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.
**So this is *not* a security feature! It is merely a visual effect!**

And because it's just a silly visual effect, it's likely to be a frustrating one for your users. I don't actually recommend using it. But now you know how to do it. Wield such power responsibly, etc.

Comment: That was exceedingly helpful , I had this idea in mind , but was not aware of layered window and window opacity. Thanks a lot!